# How to check whether a given path is a file or directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, expect, tcl

I am using the command below in my `expect` script (in tcl/Tk) for checking whether the entered path is an individual file or directory:

```
set b [exec ./check.sh $file1 | awk -F {=} {{print $1}} ]
```

The above command invokes `check.sh` file. Its contents are:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f "$1" ]] 
then
    echo "File"
else
    if [[ -d "$1" ]] 
    then
        echo "Directory"
    else 
        echo "Other"
    fi
fi
```

The command runs fine. The problem occurs when I am using the command in three parallel running scripts(the three scripts are same) it gives me an error

```
error writing "stdout": bad file number
```

because the three scripts are invoking the same file at the same time.
So, can anyone help me with this?

Here's my script:----

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

#Set the timeout time for expect command
set timeout 5

#First Argument is Ip Address
set ip [lindex $argv 0]

#Seond Argument is UserName
set user [lindex $argv 1]

#Third Argument is Password
set password [lindex $argv 2]

#Fourth Argument is Path to the source File to be copied (Keeping in mind that this path is concatenated with the second path in the program)
set file1 [lindex $argv 3]

#Fifth Argument is the destination path
set file2 [lindex $argv 4]

#Fetches the epoch time by executing "time" script
set t1 [exec ./time | awk -F {=} {{print $1}} ]

#Checks whether the path to copied is an individual file or a directory
set b [exec ./check.sh $file1 | awk -F {=} {{print $1}} ]

if { $b == "File" } {
    puts "It is a file"

    #Executes the scp command
    spawn bash -c "scp -p $file1 $user@$ip:$file2"

    #Sends the password
    expect "password:"
    send "$password\r";
    interact

    puts "Number of Files Copied: 1"
}

if { $b == "Directory" } {
    puts "It is a directory";

    #Executes the scp command
    spawn bash -c "scp -r -p $file1 $user@$ip:$file2"

    #Sends the password
    expect "password:"
    send "$password\r";
    interact

    #For calculating the number of files copied
    set c [exec find $file1 -type f | wc -l | awk -F {=} {{print $1}}]

    puts "Number of Files Copied: $c\n"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `[file isdirectory $file1]` to do that?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Could you also suggest how to fetch epoch time(in milliseconds) in expect script

Comment: `set X [clock milliseconds]`    or this: `set X [expr {[clock seconds] * 1000}]`

Comment: @BhavyaJain with "helped a lot", do you mean it answered your question?

Comment: I got my answer but I am still getting the same error

Comment: That's a TCL error when attempting to write on stdout. You'd get the same error with for instance `expect -c 'puts test' 1< /dev/null`. It's hard to think how you could get that error with that code. Are you sure that error is triggered by that part of the code?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I have shared my script

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have your answer in the comments. I'd write your code like this, which removes the need to call out to your `time` and `check.sh` scripts. It also reduces the code duplication.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# assign command line arguments to variables
#  First Argument is Ip Address
#  Seond Argument is UserName
#  Third Argument is Password
#  Fourth Argument is Path to the source File to be copied (Keeping in mind that this path is concatenated with the second path in the program)
#  Fifth Argument is the destination path

lassign $argv ip user password file1 file2

set start [clock milliseconds]

set scp_args {-p}

if {[file isdirectory $file1]} {
    puts "It is a directory"
    lappend scp_args "-r"
    set c [exec find $file1 -type f | wc -l]

} elseif {[file isfile $file1]} {
    puts "It is a file"
    set c 1

} else {
    puts "$file1 is a [file type $file1]"
    exit 1
}

puts "Number of Files to be copied: $c"

#Set the timeout time for scp command
set timeout 5

#Executes the scp command
spawn scp {*}$scp_args $file1 $user@$ip:$file2

expect "password:"
send "$password\r"

expect eof
close

set end [clock milliseconds]
set elapsed [expr {($end - $start) / 1000.0}]
puts [format "duration: %.3f seconds" $elapsed]
```

Comment: In your script,the scp command is not copying all the files in the directory.